# bug of calculating float values objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios5

does anyone knows about a bug of calculating float values (in my case currency values converted from text to float). I've been testing it on the simulator and all calculated values are correct. Then testing on the iphone device itself, every value displayed with 0.59 more. On the iPad device I've got just 0.15 more on every value.

Here's my Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// current account balance from Coredata Dataset
if (!self.FSDataSet.konto || [self.FSDataSet.konto isEqualToString:@""]) {
    self.txtKontostand.text = @"Nicht möglich!";
} else {
    // fetch request for current changes of currency values
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestFahrschueler = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([FSKontoUnterTab class])];
    NSPredicate *predicateKundenNr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kundennr == %@", self.FSDataSet.kundennr];
    fetchRequestFahrschueler.predicate = predicateKundenNr;

    // put datasets in array
    NSArray *ergebnisFahrschueler= [[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestFahrschueler error:nil];

    // variables to calculate the new account balance
    CGFloat soll;
    CGFloat haben;
    CGFloat konto;

    // account balance string converting to a flot value
    // comma replace with point
    NSString *kontostand = [self.FSDataSet.konto stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];
    CGFloat testKonto = kontostand.floatValue;

    // NSArray Iterator workaround
    // loop array and assign current dataset from entity (the managed object class)

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [ergebnisFahrschueler count]; i++) {
        FSKontoUnterTab *myset = [ergebnisFahrschueler objectAtIndex:i];


        CGFloat gesamtpreis = [myset.preis stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."].floatValue;

        // positive currency values
        CGFloat aktHaben = [myset.bar stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."].floatValue;
// calculate

        soll = soll + gesamtpreis;
        haben = haben +aktHaben;


    }
    //konto = soll-haben;
    konto = (testKonto - soll)+haben;

    // convert back to string and display in textfield
    self.txtKontostand.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", konto] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@","];
}
```

Comment: Mind if you make things more readable for english users by adding english comments?

Comment: Floating point interpretation is up to the platform/architecture. Simulator is ran under i386/64-bit, where as the actual device is a completely different target. You cannot expect consistency in floating point values between these two targets. Since I cannot understand your code, I cannot analyze it to offer assistance.

Comment: i've been changing my comments to english

Comment: I would add something like `NSLog(@"%@ / %f", myset.preis, gesamtpreis);` to the code ( and similar for `testKonto` and `gesamtPreis`) to verify that your conversion from string to float works correctly. It seems a bit locale/region dependent to me. A better solution would be to store the prices as numbers in the database instead of strings.

Comment: Floating point operations are never reliable, especial the substract operator has some pitfalls regarding Accuracy-los: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) if you want to do some serious Financial calculations you should use complex integer-based operations and only round the result to a float-value.

Comment: which datatype instead of text should I prefer to store the currency values in my CoreData entity? I can easily change my datamodel at this point of development.

Comment: I would use "Integer 32" as type in the core data model and store the value in Cent, e.g. 1234 Cent instead of 12.34 Euro. Then you have no trouble with rounding errors.

Comment: OK - I fixed the problrem - using double instead of CGFloat - no more errors, running on different devices now.